# Spotify client 0.8.8 caching javascript assets and thus developer "refresh" no longer working

Tags: spotify

I've recently upgraded my player to v. 0.8.8. I'm now no longer able to see my code changes when I do a right-click "Reload Application"

When looking at the "Network" tab in the inspector - I'm seeing that my javascript assets are pulling from cache. Also: in version 0.8.5 of the player, there was an option in the inspector settings to disable cache. This option is no longer available in version 0.8.8.

Long story short: there is no way to disable cache in the new 0.8.8 player and thus any changes to code in development require a complete restart of the application. In 0.8.5, righ-click and then "refresh" were enough.

I'm on Windows 7 x64

Spotify 0.8.5 inspector:

[image]

Spotify 0.8.8 inspector:

[image]

How can I refresh my assets without quitting out of the application in the 0.8.8 player?

Answer (score 0):

The disabling Javascript caching option will be reintroduced in a later version of the Spotify client. Unfortunately, at this point in time I can't tell you in which version or when it will be released.